# Using varargs to pass Params to a method

Tags: java, parameters, variadic-functions

I'm trying to run some benchmarking tests. I need to pass a Task and params to this method.

Benchmark(Callable task, Params params).

My code is as follows

```
     List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
     params.add("-a publish");
     params.add("-t hello/world");
     params.add("-m \"Hello MQTT World\"");
     params.add("-s 2");
     params.add("-b localhost");
     params.add("-p 1883");
     params.add("-i JavaSample");

    System.out.println("MQTT Test: " + Benchmark(task, Object... params);
```

But Eclipse is reporting these errors

Syntax error on token "...", . expected
params cannot be resolved or is not a field

I have thought of putting

> -a publish -t hello/world -m "Hello MQTT World" -s 2 -b localhost -p 1883 -i JavaSample

into the run configuration arguments to pass them to main, but with

> Benchmark(task, Object... args)

Eclipse still reports the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
Benchmark(task, Object... params)
```

You are declaring varargs in method call.To call method you should pass argument.Varargs is part of method declaration not method call.

```
BenchMark("task", new Object(), new Object());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. After a further and deeper reading of the code for the benchmark program, I've found out the Params is actually an inner class. I'm pulling this question.